# What does it mean for a manifold to be oriented?

Tags: integration, manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

I'm currently working through Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds*. I've got to Stokes' Theorem, which is stated thus (the bold is my emphasis):

**Stokes' Theorem**

If $M$ is a compact **oriented** $k$-dimensional manifold-with-boundary and $\omega$ is a $(k-1)$-form on $M$, then 
$$\int_M d \omega = \int_{\partial M} \omega $$

I've read and understood the proof Spivak gives, but I'm unsure about what **oriented** means. In applications (such as in fluid mechanics), I've sometimes seen that this condition is ignored, or hand-waved over, but it's obviously key.

I understand what is meant by an **orientation** (the fact that any non-zero $\omega \in \Lambda (\mathbb{R}^n)$ splits the bases of a linear space into two groups - those with $\omega(v_1,...,v_n) >0$ and those with $\omega(v_1,...,v_n) <0$, and these two groups are orientations for $V$), but I don't see how I would verify that a given manifold-with-boundary is oriented (other than it having *something* to do with the orientation of the tangent space).

To make things more concrete, I know (i.e. have it on good authority) that the Möbius Band is not oriented. However, I know that the 2-sphere is oriented.

> So, in short: Given a manifold-with-boundary, how do we know if it's oriented or not?

Comment: An *oriented* manifold is one for which there exists a consistent normal at each point on the manifold.  Such a consistent normal can be defined on a sphere or plane (orientable) but not on a Möbius strip or Klein bottle (non-orientable).  One can test orientability by parallel transport of a defined normal along arbitrary closed paths within the manifold.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, I don't think we want to mention parallel transport here. Moreover, your answer seems to make sense only when $M$ is a hypersurface in an orientable manifold?

Comment: Whoever downvoted this is an arse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An orientation of a manifold can be defined in various ways. Let's suppose all throughout that $M$ is a connected smooth manifold (possibly with boundary), of dimension $m$. If $\omega, \eta \in \Omega^{m}(M)$ are two non-vanishing top forms on $M$, then one can prove that there exists a non-vanishing $f \in C^{\infty}(M)$ such that $\omega = f \eta$. Since $M$ is connected and $f$ is non-vanishing, it is either positive everywhere or negative everywhere. If $f$ is positive everywhere we say $\omega$ and $\eta$ define the same orientation. In this definition, an orientation is an equivalence class of non-vanishing top forms (where the equivalence relation is "define the same orientation" as defined above). An *oriented* manifold is then a manifold $M$ along with a choice of orientation, i.e. a particular choice of a non-vanishing top form.

We usually say that $S^2$ is an orientable manifold, meaning it can be given an orientation. You would consider $S^2$ an oriented manifold if you have fix an orientation of it. One usually takes $\omega = x\ dy \wedge dz - y\ dx \wedge dz + z\ dx \wedge dy$ as the orientation for $S^2$.

It is important in Stokes' theorem to understand that if you have an oriented manifold with boundary, it induces an orientation on the boundary in a natural way. The most intuitive way that I know to explain this is the following: suppose $M$ is your connected manifold with boundary and $\omega$ is your choice of non-vanishing top form on $M$. First we fix $X$ a non-vanishing outward-pointing vector field on $\partial M$. By outward-pointing I mean that if we take coordinates $x^1, \ldots, x^m$ near a point in the boundary, and the boundary is defined by the condition $x^m = 0$, then the vector field $X$ has an everywhere negative $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^m}$ component. Such a vector field can always be obtained (construct it locally then patch it together by partitions of unity). Then we define a non-vanishing top form on $\partial M$ given by $(\iota_X \omega)(X_1, \ldots, X_{m - 1}) = \omega(X, X_1, \ldots, X_{m - 1})$.  It turns out that this choice of orientation doesn't depend on the choice of $X$, as long as it is outward-pointing (for a proof of this, see Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, in the chapter about orientations). Hence this orientation on $\partial M$ depends only on the choice of orientation we had in $M$. This is the choice of orientation we always make for the boundary of an oriented manifold.

It is important to note one thing about the induced boundary orientation. Set $\mathbb{H}^{m} = \{(x_1, \ldots, x_m) \in \mathbb{R}^{m}\ |\ x_m = 0\}$. Note that $\partial \mathbb{H}^{m} \cong \mathbb{R}^{m - 1}$. The induced boundary orientation on $\partial \mathbb{H}^{m}$ matches with the natural orientation of $\mathbb{R}^{m - 1}$ *when* $m$ *is even, but is the opposite orientation when* $m$ *is odd*.

You are correct in your belief that the oriented hypothesis here is crucial. In general, we can only integrate forms on an oriented manifold. For a non-oriented manifold, there is a more general concept of [density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_on_a_manifold).

Comment: In your example with the sphere you had defined $\omega$. Would $|\omega| = |xdy\wedge dz - ydx\wedge dz + z dx\wedge dy|$ be the corresponding density that I could integrate e.g. on a Mobius strip parametrized in some way? I have also read in various places that Stokes' theorem generalizes to non-orientable manifolds by considering the orientable double cover of a non-orientable manifold. How would that look like in terms of computations, e.g. for a parametrization of the Mobius strip?