# What is a top form?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, terminology, differential-forms, multilinear-algebra

I'm sorry for such a basic question, but I can't seem to find this term defined anywhere. I'm trying to learn analysis on manifolds, and google has not been any help in figuring out what this thing is. I know what a differential form is, what a volume form is, but I can't figure this one out for some reason.

Comment: Where did you encounter this term? Context could provide useful clues as to what the intended meaning is.

Comment: Here's an example of where I found it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237862/what-does-it-mean-for-a-manifold-to-be-oriented "An orientation of a manifold can be defined in various ways. Let's suppose all throughout that  is a connected smooth manifold (possibly with boundary), of dimension . If ,∈Ω() are two non-vanishing top forms on , then one can prove that there exists a non-vanishing ∈∞() such that =."

Comment: It may be a shorter way of saying the alternate name given here for this concept, in the more general setting of an $m$-dimensional manifold: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_form

Comment: Yes! This is it! Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On a $n$-dimensional Manifold $M$ all differential $k-$forms with $k > n$ are zero. This just comes from the fact that the $k-$th exterior powers of a $n-$dimensional vector space are trivial if $k > n$. Therefore you can only have (nontrivial) $k-$forms if $k \leq n$. So the maximal possible (i.e. top!) degree is $n$, hence these forms are called top-degree, top-dimensional or just top forms.